# Remove calendar on KDE desktop

Tags: kubuntu

There is a calendar on my desktop, I don't know how it got there, what it is or how to remove it.

It's seen in the upper left corner in this screen shot: [image: http://i.imgur.com/rQF13dV.png]

Any help on what it is or how to remove it would really be appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

Hacky solution that worked for me, similar issue, calendar stuck to Kubuntu desktop with no "x" to delete widget.

Went to `System Settings`, to group `Workspace Appearance and Behavior`, select `Workspace Behavior`, select `Workspace`, switch `Workspace Type` to `Netbook`, wait a moment for screen to change, then switch back to `Desktop`.

After this switch back and forth, the calendar stuck to my desktop was gone! :)

Comment: Using KDE under Funtoo here. This answer helped me :-).

Comment: Good thing about this solution is that the other widgets survived intact. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with Linux Mint.  Calendar just appeared and could not remove it like other desktop widgets.  Obviously, it'd clicked something, somewhere to add this but have no-idea what it was.

I managed to get rid of it by right-clicking the desktop and selecting: "Folder Settings".  I then changed the view layout from, *"Folder"* to *"Default Desktop"* and then clicking apply.

I was then able switch back to *"Folder"* as my view layout and whatever settings had created the calendar had been wiped.

Sorry, this does seem like a hack but it worked for me.  I am sure there is a setting somewhere that just removes it but like you I was unable to find it.

Comment: Not sure why I have been voted down on this answer but would be helpful if someone could leave a comment for me to explain.  Obviously, I am not looking to give answers that are considered unhelpful, so some guidance would be great. The answer I gave was genuine and given in good faith.

Comment: Your answer regarding switching "something" inspired me to try switching things while perusing system settings. I've added a trick that worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to clean it up by just killing and restarting the desktop:

```
killall plasma-desktop && plasma-desktop &
```

(This will restart the desktop, but your applications should keep running)

This happens to me when the panel is moved to the left or right side of the screen, then resized to be big enough that a calendar appears in the panel.  When the panel is then resized smaller, the widget seems to attach to the desktop instead of being deleted altogether.

Comment: I restarted plasma and the widget was gone

Answer (score 0):

This is from the [userbase.kde.org website](http://userbase.kde.org/Plasma/FAQ/4.4/Configuration/en)

> How do I remove widgets?
>
> If they're on the panel, right click on the widget and select Remove this.... If the widgets are on the desktop, you have different options:
>
> If you hover over them, clicking the X on the applet handle will remove them;
>       If you use the Add Widget dialog, you can click on the minus symbol icon next to the widget name to remove it.

There is also some more info in relation to widgets on this page.

You may also find it useful to look at the general widget settings. [Plasma Settings](http://userbase.kde.org/Plasma)

> To see the widgets that are installed on your system and ready to use open the Plasma Widget Explorer by either opening the Desktop Toolbox in the upper right corner of the screen and selecting Add Widgets, opening the Panel Toolbox furthest to the right in the Panel and selecting Add Widgets, or right clicking on the Desktop and choosing Add Widgets from the context menu. To place a widget on the Desktop simply drag it from the Widget Explorer to the Desktop. To place a widget in the panel first open the Panel Toolbox and from there open the Widget Explorer (click Add Widgets), locate the widget you wish to add and drag it to the desired position in the Panel.

Finally this is a link from the Ubuntu help pages. [CustomizeKubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CustomizeKubuntu)
Please look at the section in relation to styles where it states;

> A widget style is a plugin or a small program that instructs KDE how widgets are displayed.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @qman.  However, if the original poster had the same problem as me, there was no 'X' to remove the applet as there normally is.  This may be some weird but, not sure but the Calendar was not behaving like a normal widget.

Comment: I saw mention in your links of "quit" plasma or something, restart, which seems promising but I found another hacky method first which I added, but just thought I'd mention it for the next troubleshooter that comes along.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, but the widget I was trying to remove was on my panel.  I had a duplicate workspace switcher, but none of the answers worked for me.  However, the [answer posted here](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=66&t=123281) did:

> at the end of the panel is what is call a cashew, left click on it and the panel expands to show additional options - this will also enable you to right click and remove widgets from it

Answer (score 0):

I was able to right click on the culprit, and select "Remove this digtal clock."

It seems to have worked.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by one of these (don't know which):

1. clicked on time in Main Panel
2. activated/moved/deactivated monitor in Display Settings

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! If you manage to find out which one fixed the problem, please update your answer.